# Picasso CircleImageView resize() issue in Android 7.0 while selecting image from Gallery

Tags: android, imageview, picasso, android-7.0-nougat, circleimage

I am using CircleImageView instance to display image and loading it picked up *from Gallery or captured using camera* using Picasso library.
I am facing one issue on **Android 7.0** that is image is not loading into image view when I am resizing it. Otherwise without resizing it works fine on othere OSes.

Below is my code:

```
onActivityResult() method

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == REQUEST_PERMISSION) {
            PermissionChecker.checkPermission(activity);
        } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE)
                onSelectFromImageGallery(data);
            else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA)
                onCaptureImageResult(data);
        }
    }
```

```
onSelectFromImageGallery() method

public void  onSelectFromImageGallery(Intent data)  {
        Uri imgUri;
        if (data != null) {
            imgUri = data.getData();
            if (imgUri != null) {
                profileImagePath = imgUri.toString();
                CommonUtils.displayImage(activity, imgUri.toString(), imageView);
            } else if (data.getClipData() != null) {
                if (!StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(data.getClipData().getItemAt(0).toString())) {
                    imgUri = data.getClipData().getItemAt(0).getUri();
                    profileImagePath = imgUri.toString();
                    CommonUtils.displayImage(activity, imgUri.toString(), imageView);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

```
displayImage() method:

public static void displayImage(Context context, final String imageUri, final ImageView imageView) {
        Picasso.with(context)
                .load(imageUri)
                .error(R.drawable.default_profile_pic)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.default_profile_pic)
                .resize(200, 200)
                .centerCrop()
                .onlyScaleDown()
                .into(imageView, new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onError() {
                Log.e(TAG, "Unknown error found while setting the image.");
            }
        });
    }
```

Image will start loading once I remove `resize()`, `centerCrop()` and `onlyScaleDown()` from the code.

Comment: remove .resize() from Piccaso and use fix height and width in xml for imageview with the propertty : SCALETYPE="fitxy".

Comment: It is not working. Mine is not ImageView, it is CircleImageView. So, it is throwing error like: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ScaleType FIT_XY not supported.`

Answer (score 0):

You can resize the image the same as if you were to resize a view. Try doing something like this:

```
    imageView.getLayoutParams().height = 200;
    imageView.getLayoutParams().width = 200;
    imageView.requestLayout();
```